# printing a 3 tier multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this

```
Array
(
    [Group1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Item1] => 1
                    [Item2] => 11
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Item1] => 2
                    [Item2] => 22
                    [Item3] => 222
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Item1] => 3
                    [Item2] => 33
                )
        )

    [Group2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Item11] => 1111
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Item22] => 2222
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Item33] => 3333
                )
        )
)
```

And I need to print it out row by row.
Like this: (Items print key value)

```
`Group1` -> `1` -> `(Item1)=>'1'`
`Group1` -> `2` -> `(Item1)=>'2'`
`Group1` -> `3` -> `(Item1)=>'3'`
`Group1` -> `1` -> `(Item2)=>'11'`
`Group1` -> `2` -> `(Item2)=>'22'`
`Group1` -> `3` -> `(Item2)=>'33'`
`Group1` -> `1` -> `(Item3)=>''`
`Group1` -> `2` -> `(Item3)=>'222'`
`Group1` -> `3` -> `(Item3)=>''`
`Group2` -> `1` -> `(Item1)=>'1111'`
`Group2` -> `2` -> `(Item1)=>''`
`Group2` -> `3` -> `(Item1)=>''`
`Group2` -> `1` -> `(Item2)=>''`
`Group2` -> `2` -> `(Item2)=>'2222'`
`Group2` -> `3` -> `(Item2)=>''`
`Group2` -> `1` -> `(Item3)=>''`
`Group2` -> `2` -> `(Item3)=>''`
`Group2` -> `3` -> `(Item3)=>'3333'`
```

It has to be done Row by Row.

For `Group` its easy, just read them sequentially.
But when I reach the "MONTH" array (second tier represented by (1,2,3))
How do I write a loop to step through each "MONTH" sub array element 1.
Then again each "MONTH" sub element 2. etc.

I want to achieve something like this. (only the yellow bit is important)

[image]

**SOLUTION**

Well, Could not do it so I took a step back and tried n different approach.

Putting the "Month" in the bottom tier allowed me to use for loops suggested by `Alexey Kurilov`

Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use foreach?

```
foreach( $arr as $group => $arr1 ) {
  foreach( $arr1 as $month => $arr2 ) {
    foreach( $arr2 as $id => $item ) {
      echo $group.' -> '.$month.' -> '.$id.' -> '.$item;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The catch is it needs to be `MONTH1` -> `Item1` |||  `MONTH2` -> `Item1`  |||  `MONTH3` -> `Item1`. and then `item2` for all `MONTHS`

Comment: Check my solution. You had a role to play so I will give you the tic.